# Typescript infer keys of one property and use them in another property

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How to infer keys of object of property "objects" and used them as constraint in the parameters of functions of another property "onObject"? I don't know the keys in advance, they are defined dynamically.

```
interface Foo <Objects extends {[name: string]}: Bar = {}> {
    objects: Objects;
    onObject(name: keyof Objects): void;
}

const foo: Foo = {
    objects: {
        "a": ...,
        "b": ...,
    },
    onObject: (name: "a" | "b") => { // put constraint "a" | "b" here
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Typescript will not infer type parameters for a variable, you can however use a function to get the inference behavior you want:

```
function makeFoo<T extends { [name: string]: any }>(o: Foo<T>) {

}

interface Foo<Objects extends { [name: string]: any } = {} > {
    objects: Objects;
    onObject(name: keyof Objects): void;
}

const foo = makeFoo({
    objects: {
        "a": 0,
        "b": "...",
    },
    onObject: (name) => { // name: "a" | "b"

    }
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmAxOcA8AKopgB5SZgAmAzogN6IDaYqymAXIjVAE4xgA5gF0uqMAE9EAXwB8ACjhdcBQrICUDAFBbpOgRV7BUETIhX4A8gCMAVpmh0yFanUYs2nbnwEixkmUQAXgZpRFltRCjEODsHKBouG3tHAG4taJiwZPj5VnYuLAk4YEQcx3UuADc4GCp0vS0IBB5EYDxglAwcPHl6DOjYlISufszMgCJUCa4ABgAaAfHECesZlYA6LYnFzOldwey46C48z00giMYAemvEfK8picQAHxW1pfHPvWl1IA)